# Interpolate a dynamic template with ng-select

Tags: angular, angular2-template, string-interpolation

I want to create a component that contains an `ng-select` component to which I am passing an array of complex objects and definitions of what fields to display in the dropdown and for the selected value. With `ng-select` you specify the field to be displayed (`bindLabel`) and define a template to display the selected value (you could display one or more fields from the object, or other HTML markup). I am able to pass the value for `bindLabel`, but can't figure out how to interpolate the template.

For instance this is how I'd normally use `ng-select`. In this case I am displaying two of the object's fields and some HTML (bolding the abbreviation field), and listing the abbreviation fields in the dropdown:

**child component**

```
  items = [
    { name: 'United States', abbreviation: 'US' }, 
    { name: 'United Kingdom', abbreviation: 'UK' }, 
    { name: 'Canada', abbreviation: 'CA' }
  ];
  displayField = 'abbreviation';
```

**child template**

```
  <ng-select [items]="items" 
           bindLabel="displayField"
           [(ngModel)]="model"
           name="ngselect" 
           (change)=emitModelChanged()>
      <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
          <b>{{item.abbreviation}}</b> - {{item.name}}
      </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
```

To configure it dynamically from a parent component I pass `items`, `displayField` and `template` as Inputs:

**parent component**

```
  selectedTemplate = '<b>{{item.name}}</b> - {{item.abbreviation}}';
```

**parent template**

```
  <child-component [model]=model 
                   [items]=items
                   [displayField]="'abbreviation'"
                   [template]=selectedTemplate
                   (update)=updateModel($event)></child-component>
```

**child component**

```
  @Input() items;
  @Input() displayField; //what field shows in dropdown options
  @Input() template; // what shows for selected value in combobox
  @Input() model;
  @Output() update: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); //emit back to parent
```

**child-component template**

```
  <ng-select [items]="items" 
           bindLabel="{{displayField}}"
           [(ngModel)]="model"
           name="ngselect" 
           (change)=modelChanged()>
      <ng-template let-item="item">
          <label [innerHTML]="template"></label>
      </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

While the  bold tag of "template" is interpreted, the data fields are not interpolated, the value displays literally as

**{{item.name}}** - {{item.abbreviation}}

Is it losing scope and thus not interpolating {{item.name}} to the appropriate value? The same happens when instead of the label with innerHTML I just use {{template}}. How can I prevent this from being rendered as a string?

I likewise have the same interpolation fail with a standard <select>, it renders the options as literal strings:

```
selectField = 'item.'+this.displayField;   // (equivalent to item.abbreviation)

<select #standardSelect [(ngModel)]="model" (change)=modelChanged() >

  <!-- Also getting interpolating error here. Below renders as a string "item.abbreviation" -->
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{selectField}}</option>

  <!-- This also renders as a string -->
  <!-- <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item" [innerHTML]="selectField"></option> -->

  <!-- Hardcoded value below works -->
  <!-- <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.abbreviation}}</option> -->
</select>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q4nxz3)

Comment: Did you try `[bindLabel]="displayField"` instead of `bindLabel="{{displayField}}"`?

Comment: @noamyg Yes but the result is the same- not interpolated.

Comment: There are dynamic template options depending on the exact use case, which may differ from your simplified code. Keep in mind AOT converts templates to JS at compile time not runtime. `ngTemplateOutlet` w/ `ngTemplateOutletContext` allow passing predefined TemplateRefs from the parent. To set `innerHTML` from a string with placeholders, it may be simplest to pass `item` into a fn using a JS Template Literal. To parse arbitrary HTML from users (very dangerous!) many non-NG libs exist. NG's `DomSanitizer` and similar sanitization methods try to offer some protection against XSS and other attacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can path template into your component and render it with `ng-container`, but you need use `ContentChild` to handle template reference. for several templates use `#` naming to match them with `ContentChild` references. you can try as follow [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-select-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

use TemplateRef to reference outer template

```js
    import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'ng-select-accessible[displayField]',
      templateUrl: './ng-select-accessible.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './ng-select-accessible.component.scss' ]
    })
    export class NgSelectAccessibleComponent  {
    
      @ContentChild('labelTemplate') labelTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;;
      @ContentChild('optionTemplate') optionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;;

    }
```

use ng-container to place outer template inside of item template

```js
    <div class='styled-select' aria-hidden=true>
      <ng-select [items]="items"
                 [placeholder]=placeholder 
                 [(ngModel)]="model"
                 name="ngselect" 
                 (change)=modelChanged()
                 attr.aria-label={{ariaLabel}}>

          <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
            <ng-container 
              *ngTemplateOutlet="labelTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-template>
    
          <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
            <ng-container 
              *ngTemplateOutlet="optionTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-template>
      </ng-select>
    </div>
```

define item view in ng-template as follow

```js
    <ng-select-accessible 
                      [model]=model 
                      [items]=items
                      [displayField]="'abbreviation'"
                      [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'" 
                      (update)=updateModel($event)
                      [ariaLabel]="'Select a number'">
      <ng-template #labelTemplate let-item>               
        <label>
          <b>{{item.name}}</b> - {{item.abbreviation}}
        </label>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #optionTemplate let-item>               
        <label>
          <b>{{item.name}}</b>
        </label>
      </ng-template>

    </ng-select-accessible>
```

i think this one is a good article [about ng-template](https://unicorn-utterances.com/posts/angular-templates-start-to-source/#viewchildren-without-ng-content)

Comment: Thanks! I started down the ngTemplateOutlet approach based on rob3c's comment, and now your answer did the trick! Now I just need to figure out how to get another template working for the <select> containing an <option> (this select is a fallback for screen readers). I'm able to pass another named template but it's not rendering options yet.

Comment: @EricSoyke you are welcome. i changed the example to template both an option and a label

Comment: I needed the labelTemplate to be optional if it had nothing, it went by the default of the bindLabel

Comment: Just amazing it works like a charm